# Enlarge limits to nearest tick

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using `pgfplots` to auto-plot a number of datasets. The x-axis is in this case not to be enlarged. I'm using enlarge y limits, to get a clearer view of the data, but I would like it to scale to the nearest tick instead of a predefined percentage or value, without looking at the data manually first and using `ymin`,`ymax`.

This is what I have currently with the sample code
[image: enlarge limits]

And this is the desired plot (made with manually setting `ymin` and `ymax`)
[image: enlarge limits to nearest tick]

Thanks in advance.

Here is the sample code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[compat=newest,enlarge x limits=false,
        title=plot example,
        xlabel=x-axis,
        ylabel=y-axis,
        legend columns=-1,
        major grid style={black},
        minor tick num=1,
        grid=both,
        legend style={thick},
        enlarge y limits]
            \addplot[red,ultra thick] table[x=input,y=output]%
            {input output
            108 14.56
            110  16.25
            112  17.95
            114  19.68
            116  21.43
            118  22.99
            120  23.66
            122  24.3
            124  24.92
            126  25.56
            128  26.18
            130  26.8
            132 27.41
            };
            \addlegendentry{data}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The final axis limits are set during the visualization phase (`\end{axis}`) and can then be accessed using `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}` for example. So, afaik, the plot cannot directly ressemble to what you expect. But, after the first plot is made, you could make a second plot with the desired axis limits without too much work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be *really* cool to modify the routine for plot range calculations and make the results snap to steps of a given width. I tried reading some of the `pgfplots` source to hijack it but it got too complicated, too quickly. That's beyond me, and I'll leave that endeavour to someone more `pgfplots`-savvy.

Here I take the external route instead: using `pgfplotstable` I find the extrema of a dataset and use them pre-visualization to do the calculations to set the right keys.

**Main disadvantage**: what I wrote relies on the data range of a *single* dataset. You seem to be plotting just one at a time, so that's not a problem. If one were to plot many, using their union for the calculation would be a reasonable workaround.

**Main advantage**: the snapping procedure I define is not limited to the plot range. In fact the first parameter of `snap hi` and `snap lo` could be any key accepting an assigment. Maybe there are some neat uses for that.

Here are the code and the predictable result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread{
input output
108 14.56
110 16.25
112 17.95
114 19.68
116 21.43
118 22.99
120 23.66
122 24.30
124 24.92
126 25.56
128 26.18
130 26.80
132 27.41
}\dataset

% helper function to find extrema in table columns
\def\foldcolumn#1\of#2\with#3\into#4{%
  % get first row to initialize the cursor value
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{#1}\of{#2}%
  \let\cursor\pgfplotsretval%
  % get number of rows to initialize the cycle
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#2}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{\pgfplotsretval-1}%
  % cycle from 0 instead of 1 to gracefully handle the case N=0 (1 row table)
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,\N}{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{##1}{#1}\of{#2}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval#3\cursor}
    \if1\pgfmathresult\relax%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\cursor{\pgfplotsretval}\fi}%
  \let#4\cursor}

% styles to make it pretty
\pgfplotsset{
  snap lo/.code args={#1 to column #2 of table #3 with step #4}{%
    \foldcolumn#2\of#3\with{<}\into\minimum%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\minimum{floor(\minimum/#4)*#4}%
    \pgfkeysalso{#1=\minimum}},
  snap hi/.code args={#1 to column #2 of table #3 with step #4}{%
    \foldcolumn#2\of#3\with{>}\into\maximum%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\maximum{ceil(\maximum/#4)*#4}%
    \pgfkeysalso{#1=\maximum}},
  snap range/.style args={#1 to column #2 of table #3 with step #4}{
    snap hi={#1max to column #2 of table #3 with step #4},
    snap lo={#1min to column #2 of table #3 with step #4},},}

% styles of your MWE, nothing to see here
\pgfplotsset{
  your old styles/.style={
    compat=newest,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    title=plot example,
    xlabel=x-axis,
    ylabel=y-axis,
    legend columns=-1,
    major grid style={black},
    minor tick num=1,
    grid=both,
    legend style={thick},},}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [your old styles,
        snap range={y to column output of table {\dataset} with step 10}]
      \addplot [red, ultra thick] table [x=input,y=output] {\dataset};
      \addlegendentry{data}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: BLOOP!]